# Inherit from both 'heapq' and 'deque' in python?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, priority-queue, deque

I'am trying to implement a 'heapq' or a 'deque' dynamically (according to user's input)

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self,  choose = True ):
    self.Q = []
    self.add = self.genAdd(choose)
    self.get = self.genGet(choose)

    def genAdd(self, ch):
        if(ch == True):
            def f(Q, elem):
                return Q.append
        else:
            def f(Q):
                return heappush
        return f
```

and same for 'genGet'

the execution is correct on one side (x)or the other (but not both at the same time). I get things like

```
TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

tried multiple inhreitance but got

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

the problem is that heapq is called with

```
heappush(Q, elem)
```

and queue with

```
Q.append(elem)
```

I hope the point is clear. I think there should be a way to fix that (maybe using lambda)

Thanks

Comment: The problem is simple: `heapq` isn't a class, so you can't inherit from it. Of course you can write your own class that wraps up the `heapq` interface (or find one on the ActiveState recipes or in a PyPI package) and then multiply inherit from that, but you have to have a class.

Comment: `self.Q` is always going to be a `list` since that's how you define it in `__init__`. Inheritance is not a factor here because you are encapsulating the heap object, not inheriting from it. Why not just have a factory function that returns one or the other class?

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm not sure why you want to inherit from either. Pick the interface you want to support, and implement that interface dynamically on top of a `deque` or a `list` with the `heapq` module as appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inheritance isn't going to help here.

First, `heapq` isn't even a class, so you can't inherit from it. You can write a class that wraps up its functionality (or find one on the ActiveState recipes or in a PyPI package), but you have to have a class to inherit.

But, more importantly, the whole point of inheritance is to give you an "is-a" relationship. This thing you're building isn't-a `deque`, or a `heapq`-wrapping object, it's a thing with an interface that you've defined (`add` and `get`) that happens to use either a `deque` or a `list` with `heapq` for implementation.

So, just do that explicitly. You're trying to define a function that either calls `append` on a `deque`, or calls `heapq.heappush` on a `list`. You're not trying to write a curried function that returns a function that does the thing, just a function that does the thing.

```
def genAdd(self, ch):
    # As a side note, you don't need to compare == True, nor
    # do you need to wrap if conditions in parens.
    if ch:
        def f(elem):
            self.Q.append(elem)
    else:
        def f(elem):
            heappush(self.Q, elem)
    return f
```

There are a few other problems here. First, you definitely need to set `self.Q = deque()` instead of `self.Q = []` if you wanted a deque. And you probably want to wrap these functions up as a `types.MethodType` instead of using `self` as a closure variable (this will work, it's just less readable, because it may not be clear to many people *why* it works). And so on. But this is the fundamental problem.

---

For example:

```
from collections import deque
from heapq import heappush

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, choose=True):
        self.Q = deque() if choose else []
        self.add = self.genAdd(choose)

    def genAdd(self, ch):
        if ch:
            def f(elem):
                self.Q.append(elem)
        else:
            def f(elem):
                heappush(self.Q, elem)
        return f

d = MyClass(True)
d.add(3)
d.add(2)
print(d.Q)

h = MyClass(False)
h.add(3)
h.add(2)
print(h.Q)
```

This will print:

```
deque([3, 2])
[2, 3]
```

---

That being said, there's probably a much better design: Create a class that wraps a `deque` in your interface. Create another class that wraps a `list` with `heapq` in your interface. Create a factory function that returns one or the other:

```
class _MyClassDeque(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Q = deque()
    def add(self, elem):
        self.Q.append(elem)

class _MyClassHeap(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Q = []
    def add(self, elem):
        heappush(self.Q, elem)

def MyClass(choose=True):
    return _MyClassDeque() if choose else _MyClassHeap()
```

Now you get the same results, but the code is a lot easier to understand (and slightly more efficient, if you care…).

Comment: Unrelated: boolean parameters should use names (enforced using keywords-only parameters in Python 3). Using the class itself such as `MyClassDeque` could be used instead of the boolean parameter.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I left it out because the name `choose` doesn't really add anything. But of course the right thing to do is to rename it to something that _does_ add something, like `deque=True` instead of `choose=True`, not to just ignore it…

Comment: The "choose" wasn't a string in my original code. I just put that there for clarifying the issue and i was too hurried that i didn't figure out the choose==True. My lack of experience with pyhton and my misunderstanding of 'heapq' made me overesimate the point. Full thanks to @abernet.